Label too big compared to the text inside
When I use a CTkLabel for a text, the label appears to be much larger than the text.
How can I reduce the size of the label as close as possible to the size of the text ? Is this a bug ?
I searched on internet and tried to force the size of the label in several ways but it doesn't work...
All tracks are welcome ! THANKS
Here is an example of what I said:
The part of code :
app.text_equipe_main = CTkLabel(app.boite_affichage, height=200, text="test12",
                                font=("Bowlby One SC", 190), text_color="#f2e5cc", bg_color="blue")
app.text_equipe_main.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=35, sticky="w")

What it produce... :
https://ibb.co/WzB9k6V
The text is the right size, it is the label (here the blue rectangle) which is too high.
